# Knockout View Does not Update with geoJSON Filtered by Bounds of Google Map

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-maps, knockout.js

This script is part of a web app that allows users to display information about earthquakes on a Google Map.  The script loads google maps asynchronously and creates a Knockout ViewModel. The user can choose what earthquakes to display via some drop-down menus, which are bound to Knockout Observables (`self.curFeedType` and `self.curFeedTimeHorizon`).
The app will then display a list of earthquake titles next to the map, filtering out those which are not within the bounds of the map viewport. The earthquake data is loaded via an AJAX request from USGS.gov.

I'd like the list of displayed earthquake titles to update immediately after either of the feed types updates---this does not work currently. I believe this is an async issue---when I use the debugger it works, but not vice versa.

I know most of the functionality works because there is a separate listener that updates the UI when the map bounds change. Right now, however, the list of earthquake titles will not update until after the feed is changed and the map is moved.

```
function ControlViewModel() {
  var self = this;
  self.map = null;
  self.loadedQuakes = [];
  self.visibleQuakes = ko.observableArray();
  // types of available earthquake feeds from USGS.gov
  self.feedTypes = ["significant", "4.5", "2.5", "1.0", "all"];
  self.feedTimeHorizons = ["hour", "day", "week", "month"];
  // use significant and week as default feed when app loads
  self.curFeedType = ko.observable("significant");
  self.curFeedTimeHorizon = ko.observable("week");

  function setVisibleQuakes (bounds, quakesToFilter) {
    self.visibleQuakes(quakesToFilter.filter(quake => {
      return bounds.contains(quake.latLon);
    }));
  }

  self.updateVisibleQuakes = function(bounds, loadedQuakes) {
    loadedQuakes ? setVisibleQuakes(bounds, loadedQuakes) :
    setVisibleQuakes(bounds, self.loadedQuakes);
  }

  // Generate a url for the desired earthquake feed
  self.generateFeedUrl = function() {
   let baseFeedUrl = `https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/${self.curFeedType()}_${self.curFeedTimeHorizon()}.geojson`;
   return baseFeedUrl;
  }

  // load quakes from USGS and create new model objects
  async function getQuakeFeed() {
    let loadedQuakes = [];
    $.getJSON(self.generateFeedUrl(), function(data) {
      for (var i = 0; i < data.features.length; i++) {
       loadedQuakes.push(new earthQuakeModel(data.features[i]));
      };
    });
    return loadedQuakes;
  }

  self.updateQuakeFeed = async function() {
    if (self.map) {
      let loadedQuakes = getQuakeFeed();
      loadedQuakes.then(result => {
        self.updateVisibleQuakes(self.map.getBounds(), result);
        self.loadedQuakes = result;
      });
    }
  }

  // update the feed when either select menu changes
  self.curFeedType.subscribe(self.updateQuakeFeed, null);
  self.curFeedTimeHorizon.subscribe(self.updateQuakeFeed, null);
  // call for inital setup
  self.updateQuakeFeed();
}

var controlViewModel = new ControlViewModel();

// create a new Google Map
function initMap() {
  let map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_container'), {
    center: {lat: 0, lng: 0},
    zoom: 3
  });
  console.log(map);
  controlViewModel.map = map;
  // listener to let UI know that map bounds have changed
  map.addListener('idle', function() {
    let bounds = map.getBounds();
    controlViewModel.updateVisibleQuakes(bounds, null);
  });
}

ko.applyBindings(controlViewModel);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since asking this question, I've figured out the answer.

The following function makes an AJAX request:

```
// load quakes from USGS and create new model objects
  async function getQuakeFeed() {
    let loadedQuakes = [];
    $.getJSON(self.generateFeedUrl(), function(data) {
      for (var i = 0; i < data.features.length; i++) {
       loadedQuakes.push(new earthQuakeModel(data.features[i]));
      };
    });
    return loadedQuakes;
  }
```

Even though this function was declared as an async function, implicitly wrapping the return value in a Promise, it does not wait before immediately returning the empty array, before the AJAX request is completed. So, the promise is immediately "fulfilled" which causes the rest of the chain to fail in `self.updateQuakeFeed()`.

I corrected this issue by immediately wrapping the AJAX request in a promise and waiting for it to be fulfilled before proceeding:

```
async function getQuakeFeed() {
    return $.getJSON(self.generateFeedUrl());
  }

  self.populateQuakeModel = async function() {
    let feedResults = await getQuakeFeed();
    let newQuakes = [];
    feedResults.features.forEach(feature => {
      newQuakes.push(new earthQuakeModel(feature));
    });
    return newQuakes;
  }

  self.updateQuakeFeed = async function() {
    if (self.map) {
      let newQuakes = await self.populateQuakeModel();
      self.loadedQuakes = newQuakes;
      self.updateVisibleQuakes(self.map.getBounds());
    }
  }
```

The following guide from Google was helpful in figure this out:
[Promises "Compatibility with other libraries"](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/promises#compatibility_with_other_libraries) which discusses the value of immediately wrapping jQuery's Deferred---[the wrapper of return type from jQuery.ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)---in an actual ES6 Promise object.